# How can I export a uv normal map from unity to other programs

Tags: uv, 3d-view, normals, uv-image-editor, normal-map

Recently I started creating a room for my game, but I got stuck in a problem. In Blender I used smart UV project to my walls and added a normal map to them, the problem is: How can I export the same normal map with the same size( the wall size) into Unity or just save it as a png?
Thanks!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just for clarification - your headline says "export from unity" but you actually want to know how to save textures in Blender?

Comment: @metaphor_set I want to bake a normal map from the node editor

Comment: You can always use the edit link below your question to change or add information.